# Dynamic PHP Query - Filter Selection

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, filter

Ok Guys i need your Help One More Time Please if you can??

I have a list of drop down options as a set of filter criteria.

When each is selected, it adds it to a query string and appends an equals (=) to the selection, so if i select Large, the query would be where size = large.

I have one selection called impacted, but when a user selects impacted, i dont want the query to append = to, i want it to become where impacted LIKE 'click', so that it will search anywhere in the database column impacted.

If it remains at = to, it will only bring back a selection where there is only ONE impacted system that is stored against a lesson exactly = to the selection.

```
 SELECT p.project_id 
      , p.project_name
      , p.department
      , p.size
      , p.programme
      , l.captured_by
      , l.stage
      , l.type
      , l.impacted
      , l.depts_inv
      , l.lesson_title
      , l.lesson_learned
      , l.lesson_added 
   FROM ll_project p
   JOIN ll_lessons l
     ON l.project_id = p.project_id 
    AND l.impacted = 'Click';
```

This is how it currently pulls the code in but if someone has made a selection against the impacted filter i want the query not to add = before it but 'contains' or 'like' if you know what i mean.

Here is the full code.

```
<?php 
//Set all Variables pulled from POST of previous page
$pid = $_POST['project_id'] ;
$psize = $_POST['projectSize'] ;
$pdepts = $_POST['depts'] ;
$lstage = $_POST['stage'] ;
$ltype = $_POST['type'] ;
$impacted = $_POST['impacted'] ;
//Create Column Variable to hold Values in an array linked to the database columns
$columns = array('project_id'=>'ll_project.project_id','projectSize'=>'size','depts'=>'department','stage'=>'ll_lessons.stage','type'=>'ll_lessons.type','impacted'=>'ll_lessons.impacted');

$sqlString = null;
//Check all POSTED data is pulling through - Should be 6
//echo "Total Number Of Captured Post Variables is:";
//echo count($_POST);

$number = 0;
$queryStr = ""; 
$preStr = array(); 
//For Every POSTED Value Set the Name as Key and the Value against Each
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val ) {

if (!empty($_POST[$key])){
       if(!is_array($_POST[$key]))
       //Escape the VALUE by surrounding it with Quotes as it is a string the value would not be picked up on the query.
           $currentStr = $columns[$key]." = '".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."'"; 
       else
       $currentStr = $columns[$key]." IN (".implode(',',$_POST[$key]).")"; 
       $preStr[] = $currentStr; 
   }
 }

//set the Query String that i want to return from the Database and set the join on the BSKYB NUMBERS on both Tables
$queryStr = "SELECT ll_project.project_id, ll_project.project_name, ll_project.department, ll_project.size, ll_project.programme, ll_lessons.captured_by, ll_lessons.stage, ll_lessons.type, ll_lessons.impacted, ll_lessons.depts_inv, ll_lessons.lesson_title, ll_lessons.lesson_learned, ll_lessons.lesson_added FROM ll_project INNER JOIN ll_lessons ON ll_project.project_id = ll_lessons.project_id  WHERE ".implode(' AND ',$preStr);
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're after. Why not provide a sqlfiddle? Also, while it's great that you're escaping your data, be aware that PHP's mysql_ methods are now deprecated in favour of PDO and mysqli_

Comment: The first part of the code is what is Dynamically generated by the below code based upon a selection of filter Select Options. If a user selects the impacted filter i want the query to write impacted LIKE 'the_selection' and not as it currently works as impacted = 'the_selection'

Surely it has to do with 

currentStr = $columns[$key]." = '".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."'";

So must need to check if impacted is selected then append a LIKE operator instead of an =

Comment: Isn't that as simple as swapping '=' with 'LIKE' and wrapping $val in a couple of these; '%'?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so!

```
if ($key == 'impacted') {
       $currentStr = $columns[$key] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($val) . "%'";
     } else {
       $currentStr = $columns[$key] . " = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($val) . "'"; 
     }
       else
       $currentStr = $columns[$key]." IN (".implode(',',$_POST[$key]).")"; 
       $preStr[] = $currentStr; 
   }
}
```

Thanks for checking it out Strawberry :)